# Insert Into Array of object MongoDB Ask Question

Tags: mongodb, array

I have

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a25af80d2c4dd065991dccc"),
    "username" : "abc@gmail.com",
    "password" : "$2a$10$ptFyLKtyyrL5gMYdXS6wV.HLUA4Py5iudMJDldf5qsHFS4.9TPCyy",
    "role" : "Admin",
    "__v" : 0,
    "list" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "We",
            "arr" : [ 
                "5a26d554677475818a795f75", 
                "5a395bb0976d5304c07f7dd4"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "sandeep",
            "arr" : [ 
                "5a26d554677475818a795f75"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to add an element inside list.arr where name = 'we' and add only if the element does not exist

how do i perform this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MongoDB BOL [$position](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/position/) **MongoDB 3.6** adds fuctionality to the dollar option(`$position Operator`) directing the push operation to insert the element at the end of the array.

**Note:** **$position Operator** is a new features in `MongoDB 3.6.0`. Through which you can `set` the insertion position of element in the `array`.

Let's from beginning onward,here i want to show you . How you shall insert element in MongoDB. Along with MongoDB i am also giving simple example of `Pyhon` for your better understanding.

Suppose that in Python we have `array` object with 4 `values` like [0,1,2,3]

**Python Code Example**

```
Python 2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 20:25:58) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> array = [1,2,3,4]
>>> array[-1]
4
>>> array.insert(-1,5)
>>> array
[1, 2, 3, 5, 4]
>>>
```

This is the Python example here when saw array[-1]. It will show 4. 
i want to insert the number `5` before the last element in array. As you can see in Python.
After insert the code `array.insert(-1,5)` the array elements is `array [1,2,3,5,4]`.

Likewise i want to insert the sample array element in `MongoDB`.

Here first i have created the `position` collection in my MongoDB database. Then insert the `array` with `4 document` values. As you can see in below

**MongoDB Code Example**

```
> db.createCollection("position")
{ "ok" : 1 }
> db.position.insert({array : [1,2,3,4]})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.position.findOne()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a40c6288367f8d601e1e513"),
        "array" : [
                1,
                2,
                3,
                4
        ]
}
> db.position.update({},
... {$push : {array : {$each: [5], $position: -1 }}})
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
> db.position.findOne()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a40c6288367f8d601e1e513"),
        "array" : [
                1,
                2,
                3,
                5,
                4
        ]
}
>
```

> **Note :** Remember that `push` with no `dollar position` value specified already appends values to the end of the array.
>
> With negative values of dollar position i have more options as far as
>   where to insert a value in the array.If the absolute value of the
>   negative integer specified by the dollar poistion is greater than then
>   the push inserts the object at the beginning of the array.

Here i have given example of `Python` with `MongoDB`.

Hope this will help out to you.

For further you ref [Array Update Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update-array/)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is the new feature of 3.6, [arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.arrayFilters/index.html) what can be used with findAndModify(), update{One|Many}(), findOneAndUpdate() operations.

Comment: Through 'arrayFilters' only we can modify the value of elements in array[]. we can cannot insert the new value . Only through '$push' Operator. we can 'adds an item to an array'.

Comment: 'list' is array and with arrayFilter you can pin your action to happen only to the part of array. So your $push don't add values to all members of array, just part of them.